# How does JRuby resolve gem paths in a jar file?

Tags: jruby, rubygems

I've packaged a custom gem into a jar file which is being referenced by a JRuby script.

I'm getting the following error:

org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: JAR entry gems/sinatra-linkedin-auth-0.0.1-java/lib/sinatra/linkedin-auth.rb not found in /Users/bhaidri/code/nextgen-ui/dist/darwin-war/exploded-war/WEB-INF/lib/linkedin-gems-0.0.1.jar

When I inspect my jar file, the linkedin-auth.rb script is indeed there in the correct location.  Why is it not being correctly loaded?

Thanks,
Baq

Comment: Do you have a more complete trace? Looks like the example should work but I'd need to know more about how you built the war file and the linkedin-gems-0.0.1.jar file.

Comment: Hi Nick, So I figured this out.  It turns out that there are some strange issues going on with Tomcat's class loader.  It was reading the manifest of the new jar so that it knew the exact path of the Ruby script, but it didn't actually have the jar's classes loaded. Thus the strange error message. It wasn't enough that I redeployed the application, I had to restart Tomcat.  Once Tomcat was restarted, everything was in sync and it did resolve the path to the Ruby script in the new gem.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody runs into this situation, please try restarting Tomcat.  That resolved the problem for me.